# Extra space at the bottom of masonry layout

Tags: html, css, masonry

I'm using a masonry layout to align 3 div components with different heights in 2 columns. Here is the code:

```css
.masonry {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 1em;
  row-gap: 4em;
  gutter: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80%;
}

.left-height {
  height: 200px;
}

.right-height {
  height: 500px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="item red left-height">
    First
  </div>

  <div class="item green left-height">
    Second
  </div>

  <div class="item blue right-height">
    Third
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer yellow">
  Footer
</div>
```

Where rendered I'm getting extra space at the bottom of masonry component before the **Footer**. Is there any way to remove this space? I don't want to make items display as block, this will fix the issue but will introduce another issue which is: The third block will start from the first column and that's not what I want.

Comment: _“The third block will start from the first column and that's not what I want.”_ - then fix that with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside

Comment: Thanks. That worked!